# Drupal 7 access arguments

Tags: 7, routes

Is this right? I want to only give access to the people who have 'Download Original' checked in permissions.

```
function userDownload_menu() {
  $items['user/download'] = array(
   'title' => 'User Download',
   'page callback' => 'user_download_init',
   'access arguments' => array('Download Original'),
   'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
 );

return $items;
}
```

If this is correct it's not working for me. Otherwise how can I pass a user role to this?

Comment: Have you defined the new permissions in your module ?

Comment: Download Original is already defined in the permissions page, My thought was anyone that has this checked on the permissions page could use this module?

Comment: Have you tried with a custom `access callback` function ?

Comment: I decided not to fight it and add Hook permission, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Hook permission](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) to define the permission within your module